# CSP blocking whitelist domains in web application

Tags: content-security-policy

My project has a csp policy

```
Content-Security-Policy script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.mycompanycdn.com; report-uri mycompany.in/reportcsp
```

In the violation logs I found

```
with blocked-uri https://static.mycompanycdn.com/myscript.js
```

What could be the reason for this?